# What is the type of parameter ranges for calcHist()?

Tags: python, opencv

In the (C++) description of the function [cv2.calcHist()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d), ranges is said to be an array of arrays, each element being `[low, high]` histogram boundaries for the dimension considered in case of `uniform` histogram:

> **ranges**: Array of the dims arrays of the histogram bin boundaries in
> each dimension. When the histogram is uniform (`uniform=true`), then
> for each dimension i it is enough to specify the lower (inclusive)
> boundary `L0` of the 0-th histogram bin and the upper (exclusive)
> boundary `UhistSize[i]−1` for the last histogram bin `histSize[i]-1`.
> That is, in case of a uniform histogram each of `ranges[i]` is an array
> of 2 elements. When the histogram is not uniform (`uniform=false`),
> then each of `ranges[i]` contains `histSize[i]+1` elements:
> `L0,U0=L1,U1=L2,...,UhistSize[i]−2=LhistSize[i]−1,UhistSize[i]−1` . The
> array elements, that are not between `L0` and `UhistSize[i]−1`, are not
> counted in the histogram.

The Python binding description is just:

> `hist = cv.calcHist(images, channels, mask, histSize, ranges[, hist[, accumulate]])`

without indication of types. In most bindings C++ arrays can be replaced by lists, so `ranges` would be a list of lists.

Actually passing a list of lists triggers the cryptic error:

> `<built-in function calcHist> returned NULL without setting an error`

Code to generate this error, with two cases: single and multiple channel(s):

```
import cv2    
src = cv2.imread ('sample.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
images = [hsv]    
h_nbins = 255; s_nbins = 255
h_range = [0, 180]; s_range = [0, 256]        
# Single histogram: H
channels = [0]
nbins = [h_nbins]

ranges = [h_range] #### < -- doesn't work

hist = cv2.calcHist(hsv, channels, None, nbins, ranges)
print(hist.shape)    
# Two histograms: H x S
channels = [0, 1]
nbins = [h_nbins, s_nbins]

ranges = [h_range, s_range] #### < -- doesn't work

hist = cv2.calcHist(hsv, channels, None, nbins, ranges)
print(hist.shape)
```

What works is passing a flat list, which contains a sequence of pairs (low, high). E.g:

```
h_range = [0, 180]; s_range = [0, 256]
ranges = h_range # <-- for a single channel -- or
ranges = h_range + s_range # <-- for two channels
hist = cv2.calcHist(hsv, channels, None, nbins, ranges)
```

These types are used in this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/22/clever-girl-a-guide-to-utilizing-color-histograms-for-computer-vision-and-image-search-engines/) (other tutorials I found are related to single channel cases, generally using a tuple for the `(low, high)` boundaries, which I assume is converted by OpenCV into an array.

Question: Can someone confirm this, possibly linking to a better description of the Python binding. Is there a rational for `ranges` not following the general rule to use arrays/lists, with element related to channel `i` found at position `i`? For example here I was expecting a list of tuples. Or maybe I'm missing something and this question is silly.

Comment: The auto-generated Python wrapper of `calcHist` expects `ranges` to be something that can be converted to `std::vector<float>` -- i.e. a 1D list with an even number of elements. It then calls an [overload](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L3115), which takes the vector and converts it to plain array of arrays of floats that the documented C++ function accepts.

Comment: Specifically, that third overload ([documented here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga6ca1876785483836f72a77ced8ea759a) is the one that is marked as `CV_EXPORTS_W`, which means that's the one that a wrapper is generated for.

Comment: @DanMašek: Thanks, "*expects ranges to be something that can be converted to `std::vector<float>` -- i.e. a 1D list with an even number of elements*". That's in line with what I tested. From your two comments, I understand only the 3rd overload is accessible from Python and it should be the only one with a Python syntax in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, this is a deficiency of the auto-generated docs. Might be worth creating an issue on opencv github, since it's still like that in the latest release. | Having some understanding of how the wrappers are generated (you need to build OpenCV yourself to get the auto-generated wrapper code, and then do a fair bit of digging in the source itself), I can see that the python signature only matches the 3rd overload -- input params go first, the OutputArray becomes optional, goes after all the inputs and becomes return value, and the options with default values go after that...

Comment: @DanMašek: Ok, that's clear now, I appreciate your help and if you would like to move your comments into an answer, I'll accept with pleasure.